# How to use mustache.js inside of a site generated with Jekyll and Liquid Layouts all together

Tags: javascript, ruby, mustache, jekyll, liquid-layout

I have a site built in Jekyll for rapid prototyping of a JavaScript project I'm working on: [Choropleth](http://uberbuilder.github.com/choropleth/)

Now I've decided to introduce [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) into the project and obviously I ran into the issue of the liquid layouts {{}} syntax conflicting with mustache's syntax.

Does anyone know of a way that I can simply use the [Set Delimiter](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#set-delimiter) feature of mustache to change how mustache is working in my project?  How can I put the write syntax into my JS generated by Jekyll/Liquid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my page that I put in the _posts folder (default jekyll setup) I have the following:

```
---
layout:      test
categories:  tests
comments:    false
date:        2013-02-02 21:15:30
title:       Version 0.1.1 - geoJSON From Google Docs
subtitle:    Grab the Data from Google Docs Spreadsheet

mustacheSetDelimiter: "{{={u{ }u}=}}"
---
```

Then down below I have the following test line:

```
// Testing mustache template: use this to set new delimiter tags {{page.mustacheSetDelimiter}}
console.log(Mustache.render("{{page.mustacheSetDelimiter}} County name: {u{countyname}u}", masterGeoJSON.features[0].properties));
```

It works like a charm.

Comment: hind site: 20/20 I should have named the variable "setMustacheDelimiter"

Comment: For all of you that see this after today, I just want you to know that I spent 5+ hours looking for the reason why Mustache wasn't rendering my view (data).

I can't thank you enough, @Jeremy, for this save!!!

Answer (score 2):

I've found it to be buggy in the past (over a year ago), but I remember having to include the delimiter setting inside of my actual templates. For example:

```
{{=[[ ]]=}}

<div>There have been <strong>[[numVisits]]</strong> visits to this site!</div>

[[={{ }}=]]
```

Though I'm not sure if the initial `{{` will be interpreted correctly given that some other library is looking at the same template.